# stream_get_contents and in app verification works only sometimes

Tags: php

I am using this code to perform in-app receipt verification to apple's servers.
Everything works fine about 50% of the times this script is run.
However, on the other 50% of the time, i get an empty json response. I don't get any exceptions.
Any ideas why?

```
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

      print_r($meta);

  stream_set_timeout($fp, 200);
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
    }
  return $response;
}

$appleURL = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";

$receipt = json_encode(array("receipt-data" => $receiptdata));
$response_json = do_post_request($appleURL, $receipt);
$response = json_decode($response_json);
var_dump($response_json);
```

This is what i get when i var_dump the stream metadata

```
array(10) { ["wrapper_data"]=> array(2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["readbuf"]=> resource(6) of type (stream) } ["wrapper_type"]=> string(4) "cURL" ["stream_type"]=> string(4) "cURL" ["mode"]=> string(2) "rb" ["unread_bytes"]=> int(0) ["seekable"]=> bool(false) ["uri"]=> string(42) "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt" ["timed_out"]=> bool(false) ["blocked"]=> bool(true) ["eof"]=> bool(false) }
```

Answer (score 0):

i ran into this type of issue communicating over tcp with someone else's server. i never fully understood the root cause but got things to work by resorting to blocking [which was tolerable in the use case]

```
    stream_set_blocking ($conn, true); 
    // other stuff
    stream_set_timeout($conn, 60);
    $connResponse = stream_get_contents($conn);
```